# Facebook Graph Basic Root Information returns false (Likes)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to access the 'likes' from the following facebook page:

http://graph.facebook.com/EncuentrodeNoviosMexico

And I get the following response:

"false"

Trying to access other pages and I do get the information.

The idea is to get the 'Likes' through php or jquery/javascript (I would think through a JSON).

Questions:
1. Why does it return "false"? (Cause)
2. Is there a solution to it or an alternative to get the 'likes' from the page? (Posible Solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you need an access token to get your page's information. That is not true for some other pages like https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola.

You can do this by appending `&access_token=...` to the end of your URL.

You probably need to visit your page's Manage section and edit the settings to make it publicly visible. I'm guessing if you have country or age restrictions on your page, Facebook won't show it to anyone except for authenticated users.

Comment: I'll try to get access with the admin, but for now, I need a way to get the info without changing the privileges...

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to create a connector app. Have the page admin install your app. That way you can use the app's ID to connect and get the data without needing to do the OAuth dance.

Comment: If it isn't your page, then you'll need to authenticate each of your site's users. (I wouldn't leave my OAuth token laying around in a javascript).

Comment: Apparently it works fine in Chrome but in IE I need authentication... why, don't know... So I'll try the connector app... Any idea on a how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API Explorer returns the following with "likes" included.  Can you revise your question to include the code that does not work properly?

```
{
"id": "147931875220982",
"name": "Encuentro de Novios México",
"picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203568_147931875220982_3653853_s.jpg",
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/EncuentrodeNoviosMexico",
"likes": 1135,
"category": "Education",
"is_published": true,
"website": "www.encuentrodenovios.org",
"username": "EncuentrodeNoviosMexico",
"about": "El ENCUENTRO DE NOVIOS es un Movimiento Católico que ofrece la experiencia de un Fin de Semana, para todas aquellas parejas de novios que deseen tener una preparación pre y post matrimonial, para vivir su relación como pareja sacramentada.",
"can_post": true,
"talking_about_count": 4,
"type": "page"
}
```

Comment: Indeed I was authenticated when I tested in the Graph API Explorer.

Comment: Going into Graph API Explorer I generated an access token which I appended as recommended by cpilko but it only works with my account open, without being logged it I still get False.
How can I get an access token not dependent on my account...

Answer (score 0):

There were restrictions by country; when I eliminated them I got full access to the graph API.
Thanks to everyone. 
If they wouldn't have granted me access to the page I would have had to do what cpilko suggested. (Thanks cpilko)